# initializer list and conversion to everything, construction order

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14, initializer-list

Situation like:

```
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct C1
{
    char const* str; 
    template <typename T> operator T() const { std::cout << "Convert to " << typeid(T).name() << "\n"; return {}; }
};

struct C2
{
    C2(C1 const&) { std::cout << "C2(C1)\n"; }
    C2(std::initializer_list<std::pair<char const*, int>>) { std::cout << "C2(list)\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    C1 c1{};
    C2 c2{c1};
}
```

Output indicates that `C2(list)` is being called.

I would like `C2(C1)` to be called for `C1` argument, but I need the parameters of std::initializer list to remain deducible and convertible, and I can not replace it with variadic-templated version. I just want to control the construction order, but here //2 is not even template. Suppose type std::pair can be deserialized in normal conditions. C++14 may be used

Comment: The issue is `{}` calls `initializer_list` constructor, which has precedence over the usual constructor. What is wrong with calling it `C2 c2(c1)`? Or do you want this specific syntax in your API?

Comment: I guess you should replace `operator T` with the actual types C1 can convert to. Or even better, use a named function instead of a conversion operator and actually call the function when required.

Comment: @romeric It is not interface only for me. If I'd use it internally I'd do so

Comment: @M.M It really deserializes objects with boost deserialization, It is for that porpose, to deserialize any kind of objects user wants, and I can't to replace it with concrete type

Comment: @M.M. I was trying. It is impossible to use a named function in my case. `C1` was designed as a proxy class and is returned by iterators of some container. The `C2`  is noncopyable, nonmovable and nonallocatable whith `new` class. c2 = c1 must call a constructor of c2. Conversion c2 = c1.asT() can't be called, as moving and copying constructors for C2 is deleted. initializer_list really brakes all API

Comment: I have solved it by preventing conversion to type `std::pair<char const*, int>`, and it is not very good. Another solution is to use boost preprocessor repetition macro definitions to generate several constructors with different count of `std::pair<char const*, int>` parameters. But argument count in this case is limited. All other solutions I tried had serious issues for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following selects `C2(C1)` style for both style, `{...}` and `({...})` (in strict C++11 Standards, for the `({...})` style, it will select the second, because `C1` is an aggregate and special rules applied for it. This is no longer the case for more recent Standards.). This works by making the second constructor no longer be an initializer constructor.

```
template<typename T>
struct id { typedef T type; };

struct C1 {
    char const* str; 
    template <typename T> operator T() const 
    { std::cout << "Convert to " << typeid(T).name() << "\n"; return {}; }
};

struct C2 {
    C2(C1);
    template<typename T = std::initializer_list<std::pair<char const*, int>>>
    C2(typename id<T>::type);
};

int main() {
    C1 c1{};
    C2 c2{c1};
    C2 c21({c1});
}
```

Comment: It is good. Only to use with initializer list I need put braces twice, like `C2 c22{{ {"bbb", 3}, {"aaa", 3} }};` and not just `C2 c22{ {"bbb", 3}, {"aaa", 3} };`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the **explicit** keyword to prevent a constructor from implicit type conversions:

```
    explicit C2(std::initializer_list<std::pair<char const*, int>>) {} // 2
```

See: [What does the explicit keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)

Comment: yes. I can, but I need std::pair with convertible parameters to remain convertible, if I'll use explicit keywords, I'll lost conversion

Comment: You will need to add more constructor(s) performing allowed conversion (say, taking std::pair as a parameter).

Comment: It will be a dozen constuctors :)

Comment: I think this means that you don't really want the C1::operator T() . Maybe to consider explicit convertion methods like T& C1::asT(), const T& asT() const instead?

Comment: In this case it will trying to convert c1 even with explicit keyword. And with two versions of constructors with std::list, both explicit, will be a ambiguous overloading. It seems to be unnatural, but it is so. I have tried it.

Comment: The construction of std::initializer_list as a proxy object is not explicit

Comment: AndreyS Scherbakov. I was trying. It is impossible to use a named function in my case. `C1` was designed as a proxy class and is returned by iterators of some container. The `C2`  is noncopyable, nonmovable and nonallocatable whith `new` class. c2 = c1 must call a constructor of c2. Conversion c2 = c1.asT() can't be called, as moving and copying constructors for C2 is deleted. initializer_list really brakes all API

Comment: I mean calling C2's constructor (i.e. initialization): C2 y(c1.asT());